# Magento order state in Observer

Tags: orders, event-observer, order-status, state

I'm using observer method `sales_order_save_before` to do some operations based on order state

```
   $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
   $initialState = $order->getOrigData('state');
   $newState = $order->getData('state');
   if($initialState != $newState && $newState == 'processing'){
    // Do some operation          
    }
   if($initialState != $newState && $newState == 'complete'){
    // Do some operation          
    }
```

First validation is working fine whereas in second if loop both the conditions are not being true at the same time.

I did some modifications in order and digged dipper into its status. What I see is when first time order is placed it's **status** and **state** is processing . When order is shipped and invoiced in admin it's **status** becomes complete but **state** still remains processing. When the **status** is complete and I write a comment on this order then it's **state** becomes complete due to which second if loop is not working.

How I can validate the loop when the order state becomes complete ? (initialState should be different than newState).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the **state** is changed *after* the `sales_order_save_before` event has been dispatched.

Take a look at `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`:

```
/**
 * Processing object before save data
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    parent::_beforeSave();           <-- here the event is dispatched
    $this->_checkState();            <-- here the new state is set based on current
    ...                                  state and other conditions
}
```

Since there is no other event fired before the actual saving, your best bet is to observe `sales_order_save_after` and save the order a second time if you must.

Comment: But if I observe `sales_order_save_after`, `$order->getOrigData('state');` will not give proper result so I won't be able to do a proper comparison, right?

Comment: I don't think so. `orig_data` should only be reset *after load*. But if I'm wrong, you still can back it up in a `sales_order_save_before` observer: `$this->_origData = $order->getOrigData();` and read it in the `sales_order_save_after` observer (assuming both are in the same class and registered as singleton)

Comment: That works :) Though I would like to know how I can back it up in `sales_order_save_before` and use in `sales_order_save_after` . Should I dispatch `sales_order_save_after` method inside `sales_order_save_before` with backed parameter? Somewhere I read, I can also use registry in this case.

Comment: No need for the registry. As hinted above, by default observers are singletons and you will implement both observer methods in the same class. So you can simply add a property to the observer.